# How to handle spurious "H2077 Value assigned to '%s' never used" messages without suppressing all hints?

Tags: delphi

Delphi (10.3 Rio) emits spurious H2077 warnings for code like:

```pascal
x := TFoo.Create;
y := nil;
try
   y := function_that_can_throw;
   // use x and y
finally
   x.Free;
   y.Free;
end;
```

Note: the warning would still be unwanted even if the compiler could prove that the function cannot throw, since AFAIK there is no way to lock the function into non-throwingness by declaring it `nothrow` as in other languages *and* to assert the `nothrow` property at the call site. Hence the code must be written under the assumption that the function can throw.

I would like to suppress the unhelpful/erroneous hint, but apparently it is not possible to suppress hint H2077 specifically, only all hints or none. I would like to leave hints enabled if possible, so I'm wondering if there is another option for suppressing H2077 in this situation.

Also, I would like to avoid having to code a redundant second `try`/`finally` frame, since it clutters the source and creates unnecessary object code. The simplest and most obvious alternative - calling an empty dummy procedure like `pretend_to_use(y)` which takes a TObject parameter and does nothing with it - would create an unnecessary global dependency and most likely superfluous function calls as well. Hence I'd like your advice on a better solution...

**EDIT**: it turns out that Andreas has a point and the above snippet does not create the spurious warning (special coding in the compiler?). Here is an amended snippet that does cause the unwanted hint:

```pascal
TIdStack.IncUsage;
y := nil;
try
   y := function_that_can_throw;
   // use y and the Indy stack
finally
   TIdStack.DecUsage;
   y.Free;
end;
```

The Indy stack thing is from something I'm currently working on, but entering/leaving critical sections would perhaps be a more common situation.

Comment: "y := nil" is redundant, remove that.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: No, it is absolutely vital, should `function_that_can_throw` raise an exception (assuming `y` is a local variable). You don't want to do `y.Free` if `y` is a random pointer.

Comment: On the other hand, my experience is that this hint is almost always correct. Can you share a complete example in which this hint is displayed incorrectly? (However, the warnings "x might not have been initialized" and "return value might be undefined" are often emitted even though it is obvious that the code is correct.)

Comment: AFAIAA, you are stuck with this. RSP-13780 https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13780 would solve it - if it was to receive more votes AND EMBT could be bothered AND a certain manager could be persuaded that for example "W1057" is more "international" than "IMPLICIT_STRING_CAST"

Comment: @DarthGizka even though you don't want to, this really would be better handled using nested `try..finally` blocks, then `y := nil;` would not be needed, and thus not warned against, eg: `TIdStack.IncUsage; try y := function_that_can_throw; try { use y and the Indy stack ... } finally y.Free; end; finally TIdStack.DecUsage; end;` This also ensures that `TIdStack.DecUsage()` is still called even if `y.Free()` throws (which it shouldn't, but you never know for sure).

Comment: @ Remy: you are absolutely right. I overlooked the fact that there is no `nothrow` guarantee for `Free`, only a convention. Hence nested frames it is... Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @ Remy: I guess I unconsciously ported an old C++ idiom where the closing-type call cannot throw (deleting a POD pointer, leaving a critical section etc.). So the pattern is valid in some circumstances, but brittle. Ordering the `Free` (which could throw) before a known `nothrow` call like `LeaveCriticalSection` instead of after makes the pattern invalid, and the `DecUsage` call cannot be guaranteed to be (or to remain) `nothrow` anyway. Hence it is definitely cleaner to code nested frames, as you said.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to suppress H2077, here's how I do it.

In my "utilities include" unit I have routines like:

`procedure preventCompilerHint(I: integer); overload;`

`procedure preventCompilerHint(S: string); overload;`

These are EMPTY routines, consisting simply of `begin end;` blocks.

I simply call these routines to show the compiler that I am actually "using" the variable in question.

If you're like me & like to be able to do a build and see zero hints and zero warnings... Well, this is how I handle the H2077.

Some may say this is less than elegant. At times that may be true. At other times I simply want to suppress this hint and move on.

Do with this as you will...

**NOTE:** I removed the sample code as (a) it wasn't related to my suggestion here; and (b) it was generating more interest than the suggestion itself.

Comment: Have you ever tried whether this still works if you declare these procedures "inline"?

Comment: Firstly I think "goto NEXT_W" would be better replaced by "continue" in this case, but that aside, in this code example it looks to me like the warning is correct.

Comment: @Dsm - It's abridged code, there's work being done after the NEXT_W label (I updated my response with an ellipsis)

Comment: @Dsm - this warning is not correct (in any way that makes sense to me). `ex` is always 0 the first pass through, so `thisWordGroupID` is set to that. On subsequent passes (ex > 0), I am ensuring the same GROUP_ID (with the variable that the hint references). I know that there are always subsequent passes (`W.Elements.Count` is always >= 2).

Comment: @FreeDorfman Maybe you are missing begin/end statements. When ex =0," drop" will be set to TRUE and the break executes. Hence, unless thisWordGroupID is used outside the code shown, then the warning is correct. This is also why removing the "break" statement removes the warning.

Comment: @Dsm Wow! You just helped me find a bug in code that is about 6 weeks old. Many, many thanks! I think there are two lessons here: (1) Karma is a beautiful thing - help the [coding] universe & it will help you back; (2) Be **very wary** of simply suppressing a compiler hint without **fully** reexamining your code.

Comment: @Dsm - One final comment on the sample snippet (which I've now removed): `continue` wouldn't work as the `goto` was jumping out of two `for` loops.